# Drupal Commerce - Update profile on order without cloning?

Tags: 7, commerce

I understand the reasoning behind preserving integrity of data for existing orders tied to profiles, however...

I have a page where the user can edit the order contents and change their billing or delivery information. Instead of create a new profile, I would like to save the data directly to the order being viewed. I don't want it to affect new orders created later, either.

How can I do this? It would seem that every time commerce_customer_profile_save is called, a brand new profile is created.

This isn't a standard commerce workflow, but most of the fundamentals are there. A customer can have many open orders at any given time, and I want the flexibility for them to change the delivery address ON a specific order and save it for that order only. Someone out there has to have done this I would believe.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this leveraging Drupal's Entity API:

```
//assume we retrieved the $order_id via a page callback argument or something similar
$my_order = entity_load('commerce_order', array($order_id));

$billing_profile_id = $my_order[$order_id]->commerce_customer_billing[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['profile_id'];
$billing_profile = entity_load('commerce_customer_profile', array($billing_profile_id));

// **replace this comment with PHP logic to update the profile values**

//save our customer profile object using the updated values from logic above
$success = entity_save('commerce_customer_profile', $billing_profile[$billing_profile_id]);
```

This allows us to directly edit the customer profile object associated with a particular order, and leaves the rest of the profiles unaffected.

Comment: I had the same idea however this still causes a new profile to be created every time :(